# How to stop angular 6 HTML (change detection) function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function in my Angular html that retrieves a value from a shared object in a service. The problem is I would like Angular to turn off the change detection so that the function is not continuously executed. I am not able to run the function before since the parameter is retrieved only at ngOnInit. I have seen discussions on this question but no solution....is there a solution in 2020? This is the code:

```
.html


   <td [ngStyle]="{'border-top': ezzy.getThemeBorderColor()}" attr.dataTh="{{ezzy.LOCALIZATION.price}}">{{response.price*ezzy.getFxRate(respondedList.country) | number:'1.2-2'}}</td>

ngOnInit

    ....
    ....
        window.customSocket.emit('getRespondedList'); // GET LIST FROM SERVER
        window.customSocket.on('respondedList', (data: any) => {
          window.customSocket.off('respondedList');
          this.respondedList = data.respondedList;
          this.respondedListReponsesCount = data.dealerCount;
       .......
        });
```

Comment: what function you want execute on init? can you show more of your code? maybe a stackblitz project

Comment: @Clystian the function is executed in the HTML....ngOnInit just loads the data. The actual function can be anything.

Comment: the code is async, you can control excecution time so easy, your function is a websocket suscription and events?

Comment: @Clystian.....The code is ngOnInit aysnc but the function is just a regular function  getFxRate() in a Service. I am not sure what you mean by "control execution time..."...from what I understand Angular change detection will auto execute the function in the HTML ...If I am wrong let me know!